# magento 2 Csrf form validator does not work

Tags: magento2

My form's Csrf does not validate and always returns null.

```
if($this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())){
   //do something 
}
```

i looked into the matter and found that my custom form's Csrf key is returning a different value from the value produced from the validator key:

```
\magento\framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator::validate
```

this is what i did:

**Block :**

```
namespace Test\Aup\Block\Registration;
class AccountDetails extends Template
{
    protected $formKey;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, 
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        $data = []
    ) {
        $this->formKey   = $formKey;
        $this->_registry = $registry;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getFormKey()
    {
      return $this->formKey->getFormKey();
    } 
}
```

**View:** 
Test\Aup\view\frontend\templates\registration\accountdetails.phtml

```
 <form autocomplete="off" method="post" autocomplete="off" action="/Test/Aup/"  class="container">
     <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $block->getFormKey() ?>" />

<div class="bottom-action">
    <span class="button right">
        <input  type="submit" name="submitregister" value="Continue" class="button continue"></input>
     </span>
</div>

  </form>
```

**controller:**

```
 namespace Test\Aup\Controller\Registration;
 Class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action

{
    protected $formKey;
    protected $formKeyValidator;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey    
    )
    {
        $this->formKeyValidator  = $formKeyValidator;
        $this->formKey           =  $formKey;
        $this->_pageFactory      = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
          echo "formKey produced from the validator: \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator";
          var_dump($this->formKey->getFormKey());

        $formKeyForValidation = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue('form_key');

        echo "post returned form Key";
        var_dump($formKeyValidator);die();

        $validFormKey = $this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest()); die();
    }
}
```

The two values produce totally  different numbers. Consequently this test is failing :

```
$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest()))
```

My Magento is installed on wampp.

Comment: Can you show me your all code lines: Block, Controller, view phtml?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh  -hi. thank you for responding. i have now added the full code. please let me know if you need anything else. thanks

Comment: How you submit the form? You should have a button?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh hi Khoa. i added the submit button. sorry about that- did not realise that you would need it. thanks for your help so far

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh hi Khoa-- any thoughts on the above code